# Why is Drupal not recognizing my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

Why is the following not working:

```
(function($){

Drupal.my_module = {};

Drupal.behaviors.my_module = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {     
    $('#some-div').Drupal.my_module.doStuff(); 
  }
};

Drupal.my_module.doStuff = function(){
  this.append('Hello World');
}

})(jQuery);
```

I get this error: TypeError: $(...).Drupal is undefined

If I use another architecture like passing the selector as an argument for the function it works:

```
(function($){

Drupal.my_module = {};

Drupal.behaviors.my_module = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {     
    Drupal.my_module.doStuff($('#some-div')); 
  }
};

Drupal.my_module.doStuff = function(elem){
  elem.append('Hello World');
}

})(jQuery);
```

It also works if I declare the function in the jQuery.fn object:

```
$.fn.doStuff = function(){...do something...};  // It works
```

Then call it like:

```
$('#my-div').doStuff(); // It works
```

But I want to put it under Drupal.my_module, something more like the first case.

Any clues?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#some-div').Drupal.my_module.doStuff();
```

`Drupal` is not a valid jQuery method or property, hence the `undefined` error.